# Why don't we start a sect-wise SEs in Hinduism?

Tags: discussion, community, site-evaluation

I have been observing from 2015 onwards, though went into hibernation for quite some period, that there was lot of in-fighting/cold war among the members of this site, to prove their SUPREMACY of respective sects.

The following are a few questions, quoted for illustrative purpose.

1. [What scriptures discuss Ghandaberunda, the bird beast created by Narasimha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/191/3869)
2. [What is the story of Sharaba?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2447/3869)
3. [Do Vedas or Shruti describe Lord Shiva as Sattva (सत्व)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12387/3869)
4. [Do followers of dvaita really believe that advaitins are “deceitful demons”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28629/3869)
5. [Do the official Shankaracharya Peethams recognize the validity of Neo-Vedanta?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/32042/3869)

---

My question is not for moderators alone, here, but to the community as a whole?

Why should we keep on entertain cold war among the members, belonging to different sects, who by posting questions/answers often leading to ugly spats, spoiling the ambiance of this site?

Why do not we start different SEs for different sects, viz, Vaishnavism.SE, Shaivaism.SE, advaitins.SE,etc, so that we can avoid viewing such ugly spats in this forum?

Comment: Just wondering why are you pointing out to posts that are several years old

Comment: Yes, you can propose on area51. No harm. It does sound good.

Comment: Because he was an active member then so he might be remembering those posts vividly @Carmensandiego

Comment: You are right @Rickross

Comment: "Why do not we start different SEs for different sects, viz, Vaishnavism.SE, Shaivaism.SE, advaitins.SE,etc, so that we can avoid viewing such ugly spats in this forum?" ***And that's how sectarian thingy started in Santana Dharma after Vedic Era ended.***

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto: My idea is not to divide.  However, instead of witnessing ugly spats in the name of **mlecchha or neo-vedatin or tamasic purana or something else**, it is better to divide the sites sect-wise.  What more can we suggest to stop this unwarranted, useless debates ?  Are we learning anything new from these abhorrent debates?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv that thing is in Dharma since the beginning. I wonder what you would have done during Shankaracharya or Ramanujacharya or Madhavacharya period. When I had joined the site, being a general Hindu, I took these things otherwise like you. But slowly I started understanding more about our culture. It is full of criticism, debate etc. Now about this site, this site is not about Hindus but Hinduism as a whole. Try to understand the difference. But if you feel something is not done right, that's where SE tools come into picture. You can always use custom flag for mod attention.

Comment: Also @srimannarayanakv Can we continue discussion in Hinduism chatroom?

Comment: I have understood what Hinduism was/is and I did not post the question out of anger.  Your statement - You can always use custom flag for mod attention - made me laugh. Are moderators existing actively here ? :-) @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @sriman Tell me instead of raising meta, how many times you raised custom flags? And how many times times mods didn't handle it?

Comment: I don't know the difference between raising "custom flag" and posting in "meta". I am a person with ordinary intelligence.  In had interacted with moderators from 2015 onwards, in comments section, meta and through help Centre.  Nil response. BTW why are you showing so much anguish? I don't think heavens will fall down with my meta post.  At worst I will be suspended or my account will be closed by mods. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Looks like you failed to understand me. First of all I am not showing any anguish.If you read the comments carefully I tried to explain, but your respond were ***"Your statement - You can always use custom flag for mod attention - made me laugh."***  Anyway I am not here for that. All I am asking you to learn the tools. For mod attention, use custom flags. check this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpj9z.png If you'll click on flag, it'll show the popup as shown in image. Select the moderator attention one and write whatever is wrong.

Comment: I don't want to communicate with moderators,who are in dormant stage.  Thanks for spending your valuable time in posting your suggestions @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @srimannarayanakv bro! please understand mods are also users like us. They will have their personal commitments too. Sometimes they will be away from accessing sites frequently. In such cases only flags are the way to communicate with them.

Comment: The misunderstanding is leading to sarcasm and all other worse things. I think most of the misunderstandings are coming from off-topic posts. Though the on-topic contents pretty well documented, people are still asking off-topic ones. This should be fixed (I don't know how)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there is no cold war. I can understand the angst if the feeling is that neutral/outsiders can get influenced into believing that a particular God is considered superior in Hinduism.  But it is a bit too much to expect a poster to overcome his or her bias.

I would rather have bias in the post as long as it is backed by non-interpolated scriptures than a neutral post backed by just opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good idea. Please propose.

Only two questions -

1. I see that some Hindus may not fall into any of these sub-groups.  How to handle that?
2. Should HSE be dissolved if above proposal is given a go ahead? If HSE is not dissolved, then the situation will continue.

Comment: I do not know about technicalities and feasibility, but the following are my proposals.

Comment: 1. The Hinduism.SE will continue to be the mother SE, 2) under which different sub-SEs should be opened based on sect. 3) Each member can choose the sub-SE of his/her choice.